# passing dynamic data through props

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to pass data as props to an encapsulated component.

I need to change that date as it is changing in the parent.

But nor directly passed (like `textCaption`), nor passed as a function-generated - does not allow to update data in the child upon state change in the parent.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this._statData = props.textData;
    this._dynData = props.funcData;

  }

  render() {
    console.log(`Render MyComponent with static=${this._statData} dynamic=${this._dynData()}`)
    return (
      <Text>static: { this._statData} / dyn: { this._dynData()}</Text>
    )
  }
}

const Container = () => {
  const [textCaption, setTextCaption] = React.useState("Textual")
  const [funcCaption, setFuncCaption] = React.useState("Functional");
  console.log(`textCaption: ${textCaption}, funcCaption: ${funcCaption}`)
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Button title="Change" onPress={()=>{ 
        console.log(`Update dynamic prop`)
        setTextCaption(textCaption + "!")
        setFuncCaption(funcCaption + "!")
      }}/>
      <MyComponent textData={textCaption} funcData={()=>funcCaption}/>
    </View>
  )
}

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <Container/>
  }
}
```

https://snack.expo.io/SJYuSqIEL

What's wrong with my approach?

**UPDATE**

Thanks to @Ian Vasco for the answer below - it shows how to get it working with using of functional-style for React component.

But for me the question now is why `()=>funcCaption` passed to `<MyComponent textData={textCaption} funcData={()=>funcCaption}/>` always returns initial value of `funcCaption`?

But when I change use `<MyComponent textData={textCaption} funcData={()=>Math.random()}/>` - it shows new generated value every time!

Comment: You want both `statData` and `dynData` to be updated?

Comment: No, I just need a way. That are my attempts.

Answer (score 1):

So, the problem in the example you provided is that you are using the constructor which will take a stale value and then you are not assigning again. I like that you started to use React Hooks, so I will refactor your unnecessary class based component. This is the example

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet , Button} from 'react-native';

const MyComponent = (props) => {

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`Render MyComponent with static=${props.textData} dynamic=${props.funcData}`)
  }, [props])
    return (
      <Text>static: { props.textData} / dyn: { props.funcData}</Text>
    )
}

const Container = () => {
  const [textCaption, setTextCaption] = React.useState("Textual")
  const [funcCaption, setFuncCaption] = React.useState("Functional");
  console.log(`textCaption: ${textCaption}, funcCaption: ${funcCaption}`)
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Button title="Change" onPress={()=>{ 
        console.log(`Update dynamic prop`)
        setTextCaption((prev) => prev + "!")
        setFuncCaption((prev) => prev + "!")
      }}/>
      <MyComponent textData={textCaption} funcData={funcCaption}/>
    </View>
  )
}

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <Container/>
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  }
});
```

So, as said above, I refactored `MyComponent` to be a functional component. Is the same logic than `Container`. If you are not familiar with the `useEffect` hook, it is a function that will be triggered when the dependencies changes, in this case `props`, so you can see that the value has changed.

Another thing that could be improved, is that in `Container` you were setting the state like `setState(state + "!")`, which can cause problem because `state` could not be updated with the latest value. The proper way to do it is to take a callback with the `previous` state like shown in the code.

Comment: First of all, thank you! But do you have an answer why my code isn’t working? Specifically, I am curious why it doesn’t work with the functional prop?

Comment: Sorry, for not being that specific. The problem is that the constructor is used to initialize the values. If you want to assign props to custom variable you need to use the `life cycle methods` to watch for value changes and then change both `statData` and `dynData`

Comment: And one more question: is it normal to use `useEffect` for rendering purposes? And how its result is passed back? Because I thought `useEffect` as, perhaps, “detached” call - I mean, that the caller is not dependent on its result and compiler/interpreter can just drop it or even move to separate thread..

Comment: What do you mean by using the useEffect for rendering purposes?

Comment: Oh, I am sorry, I am reading on a phone and the code structure of MyComponent looked like useEffect callback was returning `(<Text...`. Sorry, it’s my mess(

Comment: But the question about functional prop is still actual for me.. Ok, I assign this fiction in the constructor, and the function itself isn’t changing. But why the function return result as if its arguments were not changed, though, they have been changed in the parent?

Comment: Are we talking about the class based component in your code, right? So, as I said before, the constructor only works to initialize the values. For instance, when you first created the component it will call the constructor just once, then the component will be mounted and your variables will point to an older value. It's fine if you only reach the props value without assigning it to another var in the constructor.

Comment: Yes, it’s about my class. I understand about constructors.. But in the constructor, the value `this._dynData` receives a function (in my example) - not plain data. And I expected do get different results on calling that function, because the function refers to external data that is changing. (I know update of MyComponent is triggered by textCaption change only)